# Tesseract OCR error, probably because of traineddata

Tags: python, python-3.x, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am using **pytesseract** wrapper, with **Legacy Tesseract** (oem 0). This is my code line to extract text from image:

```
try:
    # extracting ocr data from image
    ocr_data = pytesseract.image_to_data(
        img, lang="eng", output_type=pytesseract.Output.DATAFRAME,
        config="--oem 0"
    )

except Exception as e:
    print("Trace:", e)
```

**Error trace:**

> Trace: Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v4.0.1 with Leptonica
>   Warning: Invalid resolution 0 dpi. Using 70 instead.
>   Estimating resolution as 389
>   tesseract: intmatcher.cpp:1160: void ScratchEvidence::UpdateSumOfProtoEvidences(INT_CLASS, BIT_VECTOR): Assertion `ClassTemplate->ProtoLengths[ActualProtoNum] < MAX_PROTO_INDEX' failed.
>   Aborted (core dumped)

I have also tried with command line tesseract and getting exactly same error. command used:

```
tesseract img.png out --oem 0 -l eng
```

I am using Tessdata files given on this link:
https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata

**I searched on google but couldn't find any help!**

Comment: Could you show us, type of `img` variable?

Comment: type of image is
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>

image is loaded using cv2.imread("img.png")